# caught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'continue' on 'IDBCursor': The cursor is being iterated or has iterated past its end

Tags: typescript, indexeddb

when I am doing page query in indexeddb with google chrome browser like this:

```
export async function getPage<T>(page: number, pageSize: number): Promise<T[]> {
    let transaction = (await db).transaction(["prompt"], "readonly");
    let store = transaction.objectStore("prompt");
    const cursor = await store.index("promptIdIndex").openCursor(null,'next');
    let offset = (page - 1) * pageSize;
    const data: T[] = [];
    while (cursor && offset > 0) {
        if(cursor && cursor.key){
            cursor.advance(offset);
            offset -= cursor.key as number;
        }
    }
    for (let i = 0; cursor && i < pageSize; i++) {
        if(cursor && cursor.key){
            data.push(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

the console shows error:

```
caught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'continue' on 'IDBCursor': The cursor is being iterated or has iterated past its end.
```

what should I do to fixed this issue? I have tried to add the cursor edge condition. seems still did not work. This is the full typescript file:

```
import { openDB, DBSchema } from 'idb';

interface GenieDB {
    prompt: {
        name: string;
        id: number;
    };
}

export interface Prompt {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

const db = openDB<GenieDB>('genie', 1, {
    upgrade(db) {
        const promptStore = db.createObjectStore('prompt', {
            keyPath: 'id',
            autoIncrement: true,
        });
        promptStore.createIndex("promptIdIndex", "id", { unique: true });
    },
});

export async function getPage<T>(page: number, pageSize: number): Promise<T[]> {
    let transaction = (await db).transaction(["prompt"], "readonly");
    let store = transaction.objectStore("prompt");
    const cursor = await store.index("promptIdIndex").openCursor(null,'next');
    let offset = (page - 1) * pageSize;
    const data: T[] = [];
    while (cursor && offset > 0) {
        if(cursor && cursor.key){
            cursor.advance(offset);
            offset -= cursor.key as number;
        }
    }
    for (let i = 0; cursor && i < pageSize; i++) {
        if(cursor && cursor.key){
            data.push(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

I have tried to add this condition to check the cursor could continue:

```
if(cursor && cursor.value && cursor.continue){
            data.push(cursor.value);
            debugger
            cursor.continue();
        }
```

still could not work.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `cursor.advance()` and `cursor.continue()` in a synchronous loop, without waiting for those asynchronous requests to actually complete. If you unroll the `while` loop this is like calling `cursor.advance(offset); cursor.advance(offset);` which gives you the error - the first call asks the cursor to asynchronously go off and iterate, and then the second call throws an exception to let you know it hasn't completed yet.

What's unclear is if you're using an async wrapper around IndexedDB already, since you call `await ...openCursor(null,'next');` even though IndexedDB methods *don't* natively return await-able promises. If you're already using a wrapper, look at the the documentation for the wrapper that explains how to `await` the `advance()` and `continue()` calls.

If you're not using a wrapper already, but using the low level API directly, consider a helper like this:

```js
function promiseForRequest(request) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.onsuccess = () => { resolve(request.result); };
    request.onerror = () => { reject(request.error); };
  });
}
```

Then you'll want to modify your code like:

```js
let cursor = await promiseForRequest(store.index("promptIdIndex").openCursor(null,'next'));
```

and:

```js
cursor = await promiseForRequest(cursor.advance(offset));
```

and:

```js
cursor = await promiseForRequest(cursor.continue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Joshua Bell's reasoning and explanation is correct, but the proposed code will not work, because `cursor.continue()` returns `undefined`, instead of an  `IDBRequest` object suitable for `promiseForRequest`.

Looking at the MDN example for the `continue()` method, you can see that the `success` event for the `IDBRequest` object returned by `openCursor()` gets triggered on `continue()` calls as well. Therefore, you could do the following:

```
// Helper from Joshua Bell's answer
function promiseForRequest(request) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.onsuccess = () => { resolve(request.result); };
    request.onerror = () => { reject(request.error); };
  });
}

// Hold reference to the cursor request, since its `success` event is triggered when we iterate through the cursor
const cursorReq = store.index("promptIdIndex").openCursor(null,'next');
let cursor = await promiseForRequest(cursorReq);
while (cursor) {
   // ... use `cursor`

   cursor.continue();
   await promiseForRequest(cursorReq);
}
```